# Python 3.x - Data Annotation Validation Equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, assertions

I am trying to identify a way to implement same concept as data annotation validation from .NET in Python. It would be something like the following:

```
class MyClass:
    @Property
    def Message(self):
        return self._message

    @Message.setter
    @MaxValue(233)
    def Message(self, value):
        self._message = value
```

I have tried different approaches but with out success. I would like to get access to "value" argument in order to apply a specific validation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does This help you?

This way you can make python annotations with additional arguments

```
def MaxValue(maxValue):
    def wrapFunction(function):
        def replacedMaxValueFunction(self, value):
            assert value <= maxValue
            return function(self, value)
        replacedMaxValueFunction.__name__ = function.__name__
        return replacedMaxValueFunction
    return wrapFunction
```

So now you can do this: 
I do not know wether it is C# conform but hopefully it does the checking you desire.

```
>>> @MaxValue(123)
def f(self, value):
    print(value)
>>> f(1, 123)
123
>>> f(1, 124)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    f(1, 124)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 4, in replacedMaxValueFunction
    assert value <= maxValue
AssertionError
```

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks a lot for the hint.It is much appreciated.